# How do you update the draft version of Dialogflow Phone Gateway?

Tags: dialogflow-es

*Original question in forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dialogflow/H2nG9UM8fvM;context-place=forum/dialogflow*

As I'm making changes to a draft Dialogflow, I can demo the changes on just about every platform within a few minutes. Some propagate the update automatically such as Google Assistant and Text via Twilio but there seems to be no way to update the **Dialogflow Phone Gateway** draft version.

I've even tried to delete (an hence lose my assigned number) and then reenable the integration.

Does anybody know of a way?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Dialogflow settings -> Environments -> Publish a version -> Add a description -> Choose New Environment (This will be the new environment you are creating besides Draft) -> Write the environment name -> Select all the options you want -> Then, publish it.
Now you will have more environments to select.

Answer (score -1):

Dialogflow's phone gateway is tied to a specific version of your Dialogflow agent.  You can change which version that the phone gateway uses (including the draft environment) in Dialogflow's console > Integrations > Phone Gateway > Environment.  In the screenshot below the environment the phone gateway is using is the draft environment:

[image]

This can be changed by selecting a different environment from the dropbox list box.

Comment: But I don't have environments, I only have "draft" which is what I'm currently working on. I'd like to propagate draft changes without "publishing".

Comment: make sure the environment for the phone integration is set to draft as indicated in the screenshot above